# display items in a database in a webpage and edit

Tags: python, django

I am getting the below error when I tried to run the edit part.

Displaying the contents of database in webpage is working fine. I have put up code for just the edit part.

> TypeError at /edit/ 
>   `__init__()` takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

views.py

```
class userUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = user
    fields = ['name','phone','dob','gender']
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from newapp import views
urlpatterns = [url(r'^edit/',views.userUpdate, name = 'user_update_form'),]
```

user_update_form.html

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
</form>
```

Comment: get all objects by Mymodel.objects.all() and send by context in a view to templates.

Comment: I removed most of the code that couldn't have anything to do with the issue. (See [MCVE]). You should show the complete error and include what you've done so far yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class-based views need to be referenced in urls.py via their `as_view` method:

```
url(r'^edit/', views.userUpdate.as_view(), name = 'user_update_form'),
```

Comment: thank u so much Daniel. I am not getting that error any more, but i am getting this "Generic detail view userUpdate must be called with either an object pk or a slug."

Comment: Well, it needs to have some way of knowing what object to edit, clearly.